# custom pattern not deforming with surface deform modifier

Tags: modifiers

I've made a custom pattern and trying to deform it with the circle shape as a target, but when I deform the circle, the custom pattern doesn't deform. I can however scale the target circle, and the custom pattern also scales up and down, so it is binded together, but it just does not deform.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind, make sure that the circle is over the grid. To correct the current situation, unbind your grid, scale it up until it is bigger, select the circle, go in *Edit* mode, flatten it on Z, put it over the grid in *Object* mode, in *Edit* mode scale it until it is as big as your grid, bind the grid again.

[image]